# Which internal-sftp options are available?

Tags: sftp, openssh

I had to create a `chroot` environment in a RHEL 6 box and I used the `internal-sftp` server of OpenSSH. The following OpenSSH configuration lines are working:

```
# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

Match User jaileduser
  ChrootDirectory %h
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
#  ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /xxx
```

But, by googling this issue, I realized that `internal-sftp` has some options, like `-d`, but I have found no information/help about its options/arguments and their meanings in the manual pages.

Then I downloaded OpenSSH 5.6p1 source code, hoping it would be easy to find those options. But it appears to be harder than I ever thought. I found this in the `Changelog` file

```
 - djm@cvs.openbsd.org 2008/08/21 04:09:57
   [session.c]
   allow ForceCommand internal-sftp with arguments. based on patch from
   michael.barabanov AT gmail.com; ok markus@
```

Do anybody can tell me where I can find this info?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `internal-sftp` supports the same set of options as the `sftp-server`:
https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server

Both are built from the very same code.
See also [Difference between OpenSSH internal-sftp and sftp-server](https://serverfault.com/q/660160/168875)